# PHP with Advanced Custom Fields - hide field in a repeater if its not there in backend of Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Looking to hide a repeater a field in a repeater function but only hide the EMPTY field. I was going to create another separate repeater but this is more flexible if the client wants double sizing at some point.

The repeater function is working nicely. The image [https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1nF6.png]

The code is:

```
<?php 

// check for rows (parent repeater)
if( have_rows('wine_typesection', $child_id) ): ?>
    <div id="wine_typesection">
    <?php 

    // loop through rows (parent repeater)
    while( have_rows('wine_typesection', $child_id) ): the_row(); ?>
        
        
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">

        <h4 class="menu-title-center-pad"><?php the_sub_field('wine_sectionmaintitle', $child_id); ?></h4>
        <div id="row-divider-sm" class="col-xs-6">

        <!-- lines -->
        <div class="menu-line-dark-menu-divider">
            <div class="c-border-line-dark-l"></div>
            <div class="c-border-line-dark-m"></div>
            <div class="c-border-line-dark-r"></div>
        </div>


        <div class="module-content-small">
        <ul class="pour-size">
                <li><?php the_sub_field('pour_sizelft', $child_id); ?></li>
                <li><?php the_sub_field('pour_sizeright', $child_id); ?></li>
        </ul>
        </div>


        </div>
        </div>

            <?php 

            // check for rows (sub repeater)
            if( have_rows('wine_menuitemlist') ): ?>
                
                <div class="col-sm-12 contentPane">
                <div class="DNNModuleContent">
                


                <ul class="module-content-serif">
                <?php 
                // loop through rows (sub repeater)
                while( have_rows('wine_menuitemlist') ): the_row();
                    // display list
                ?>

<li>
<?php the_sub_field('wine_name'); ?>
<var><?php the_sub_field('wineprice_pourleft'); ?></var>
<dd><?php the_sub_field('wineprice_pourright'); ?></dd>
</li>

<?php endwhile; ?>

                </ul> <!-- ul -->
                </div>
                </div>

            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>    

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The 2 parts that i'd like to NOT show if it's empty is:

```
<li><?php the_sub_field('pour_sizeright', $child_id); ?></li>
```

AND

```
<dd><?php the_sub_field('wineprice_pourright'); ?></dd>
```

Comment: Use simple if statement

Comment: `if(get_sub_field('pour_sizeright', $child_id))` - `the_sub_field()` echoes it automatically. `get_sub_field()` doesn't.

Comment: The issue is that b/c it's in a repeater field, it applies it to every field if only one field is empty. 

For example i have inside of a repeater function in advanced custom fields:

<?php if( get_field('wine_mainsectiontitle') ): ?><h2><?php the_sub_field('wine_mainsectiontitle', $child_id); ?></h2><?php endif; ?>

And i have 2 repeater sections. One has the title. One doesn't but they both don't show now.